# What is the significance of this line by Loki in Infinity War?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In Infinity War, just before he is killed, Loki says:

> You will never be a God.

As far as I remember, I don't think Thanos has been portrayed as wanting to become a God in the MCU. I understand that he has a superiority complex that he is the only one who knows and understands what needs to be done, as well as it his burden to do what is needed but I would hardly call it a God complex. Even after he has performed the Snap, he destroys the stones and goes back to a "normal" life in the Garden.

So what Loki says, is it supposed to be a reference to something?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/avnu46/what_did_loki_mean_when_he_told_thanos_that_he/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanos saw himself as a savior. Joe Russo [said](https://www.thewrap.com/infinity-war-directors-explain-thanos-double-universe-resources/):

> So his messianic complex — he is now committed to following through on
> the idea he had many many years ago. He is not a stable — although he
> appears stable at times, he is not a stable individual.

On Titan, Thanos says to Doctor Strange:

> I finally rest. And watch the sun rise on a grateful universe. The
> hardest choices require the strongest wills.